# How do i make my background-image in css show?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make my background image show as in the photo below:[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn4c1.png)

But yet,it does not show up like intended when i try to make it work:[reality result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgVZU.png)

Here's my CSS code:

```
.child2 img{
  background-image: url('/assets/images/imageborder.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-size:400px 30px;
}
```

HTML part:

```
  <div class="Parents">
    <div class="child1">
      <h4>Infrastructure</h4>
      <p>We innovate & supply effective planting system. Provide consultation, design, build & transfer of a
        non-toxic farm.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <img src="assets/images/infrastructure.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I dont understand,I made everything perfect and yet the background doesn't show up somehow.....
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: can you send me all the codes, a little confused to understand

Comment: a bit hard to read, you can edit your question and add the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-image:` in CSS is applying image to any `<div>` or `<span>` tag and more. You don't need to use `<img>` tag. You need to add background image to parent DOM element which contain content you want to display in front.

```html
<div class="parents">
    <div class="child1">
      <h4>Infrastructure</h4>
      <p>We innovate & supply effective planting system. Provide consultation, design, build & transfer of a
        non-toxic farm.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.parents{
  background-image: url('/assets/images/imageborder.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-size:400px 30px;
}
```

Keep in mind that `background-image` above will be fixed to the position of `parents` DOM element.

If you want to make a fixed background-image to whole page you need to do this like that:

```html
<body>
<div class="Parents">
    <div class="child1">
      <h4>Infrastructure</h4>
      <p>We innovate & supply effective planting system. Provide consultation, design, build & transfer of a
        non-toxic farm.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background-image"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
.background-image {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('assets/icons/google.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What im trying to do is add a background to the image part of my division to be honest.This helped a lot but im sorry for not explaining in detail of what i was going to do....

Comment: @randomcoder66785 I just added more information how you can attach background image. Just in case someone will read it and might have different needs.

Comment: @randomcoder66785 If answer solves your problem, you can give near answer arrow up and below arrows mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help,if you want to make a background image, then you have to put the style in the wrapper of the sentence,I've tried it and it works

```css
.Parents{
  background-image: url('/assets/images/imageborder.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-size:400px 30px
}
```

```html
  <div class="Parents"> 
        <div class="child1">
         <h4>Infrastructure</h4>
         <p>We innovate & supply effective planting system. Provide consultation,               design, build & transfer of HAVVA non-toxic farm.</p>
     </div> 
    <!-- <div class="child2"> 
        <img src="assets/images/infrastructure.png">
     </div>  -->
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: You can read here for more details